# how to implement data entry validation

Tags: c

I want to make a function so that it checks the range of input values along with fool protection, that is, if the field should store a numeric value, then the user could not enter string values. Here is what function I got:

```
void ENTER_DATA(struct DATA* notebook)
{
    scanf("%s", notebook->surname);
    scanf("%s", notebook->name);
    scanf("%s", notebook->patronymic);
    /*scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthDate);*/
    notebook->BirthDate = CHECK("Enter your date of birth:\nDay ->");
    scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthMonth);
    scanf("%u", &notebook->BirthYear);
    scanf("%s", notebook->addresSTREET);
    scanf("%u", &notebook->addresHOME);
    scanf("%u", &notebook->mobileNUMBER);
}
```

and here is where it will be called from:

```
int CHECK(const char* msg)
{
    char userGetLine[256]; //string to read
    unsigned int user_number; //total number

    while (getchar() != '\n');
    printf("%s", msg);
    fgets(userGetLine, sizeof(userGetLine), stdin); //reading the string

    while (sscanf(userGetLine, "%u", &user_number) != 1 )
    {
        printf("Error. Try again\n-> "); // we display an error message
        fgets(userGetLine, sizeof(userGetLine), stdin); // and re-read the string
    }
    return user_number;
}
```

when you run the code, an error occurs: [Debug Assertion Failed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhWde.png)
please help me finish it, I do not know what the problem is(
here I threw off the entire program - https://ideone.com/3mC4fy

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. We cannot compile and run your code snippet. Please copy&paste the full error message. I don't see an obvious reason for the error message. Maybe it depends on code you did not show.

Comment: @Bodo i edited my question, look it

Comment: `scanf` does have a return value (number of items that were successfully read)  that i worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is checking the range in CHECK, it should be checked like this:
`while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 || user_number < a || user_number > b )`
It is also unclear why to pass user_number to CHECK, its value is not used, and scanf overwrites it. CHECK asks you to repeat the input until the correct value is entered, and then returns it. But the calling code ignores this value. The getchar loop is not needed. It would be necessary to rewrite the check for example like this:

```
nt CHECK(int a, int b)
{
    int user_number;
    while (scanf("%d", &user_number) != 1 ||  user_number < a || user_number > b )
    {
            printf("Error. Try again\n-> ");
    }
    return user_number;
}

void ENTER_DATA(struct DATA* notebook)
{
...
notebook->BirthDate = CHECK(1,31);
...
}
```